# Enforce same color palette for `color` and `fill` of a subset of data

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having the following sample dataset:

```
set.seed(20)
N <- 20
df1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(N), 
                  y = rnorm(N), 
                  grp = paste0('grp_', sample(1:500, N, T)), 
                  lab = sample(letters, N, T))

#        x      y     grp   lab
# 1   1.163  0.237 grp_104   w
# 2  -0.586 -0.144 grp_448   y
# 3   1.785  0.722  grp_31   m
# 4  -1.333  0.370 grp_471   z
# 5  -0.447 -0.242 grp_356   o
```

I want to plot all points but label only subset of them (say, those `df1$x>0`). It works fine when I use the same `color=grp` aesthetics for both `geom_point` and `geom_text`:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=x,y=y,color=grp))+
  geom_point(size=4) +
  geom_text(aes(label=lab),data=df1[df1$x>1,],size=5,hjust=1,vjust=1)+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image: example1]

But if I want to change points design to `fill=grp`, colors of labels do not match anymore:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point(aes(fill=grp),size=4,shape=21) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=lab,color=grp),data=df1[df1$x>1,],size=5,hjust=1,vjust=1)+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image: example2]

I understand palette is different because levels of the subset are not the same as levels of the whole dataset. But what would be the simplest solution to enforce using the same palette?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue arises from different factor levels for the text and fill colours. We can avoid dropping unused factor levels by using `drop = FALSE` inside `scale_*_discrete`:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point(aes(fill=grp),size=4,shape=21) +
  geom_text(aes(label=lab,color=grp),data=df1[df1$x>1,],size=5,hjust=1,vjust=1)+
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  scale_fill_discrete(drop = F) +
  scale_colour_discrete(drop = F)
```

[image]

---

### Update

With your real data we need to make sure that `grp` is in fact a `factor`.

```
# Load sample data
load("df1.Rdat")

# Make sure `grp` is a factor
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(grp = factor(grp))
# Or in base R
# df1$grp = factor(df1$grp)

# Same as before
ggplot(df1, aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point(aes(fill=grp),size=4,shape=21) +
  geom_text(aes(label=lab,color=grp),data=df1[df1$x>1,],size=5,hjust=1,vjust=1)+
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  scale_fill_discrete(drop = F) +
  scale_colour_discrete(drop = F)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! I really like your solution, but... for some weird reason it doesn't work when I apply _exactly_ the same code to my real dataset. I would be very grateful if you could take a look, I've saved it here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/htndrzurpbogyxk/df1.Rdat?dl=1 - just download then `load('df1.Rdat')`, you'll see that the label colors don't match...

Comment: @VasilyA You need to make sure that `grp` is a `factor` (not a `character` vector). I have updated my answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to leave the colour / fill palettes alone, & set all unwanted labels to be transparent instead:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = grp), size = 4, shape = 21) +
  geom_text(aes(label = lab, color = grp,
                alpha = x > 1),
            size = 5, hjust = 1, vjust = 1) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("TRUE" = 1, "FALSE" = 0)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: thank you @Z.Lin, it's a smart workaround! The only issue that rendering the plot with this code is quite slow on my real dataset that has 800 datapoints and same number of levels of `grp`...